# residue theorem to evaluate an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have encountered a problem;

Use Residue theorem to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin z}{(z^2+4)(z^2 -2z +2)} \, dz$

How is this done?

Comment: $\sin z$ grows exponentially fast along the imaginary axis. Use the residue theorem on $$\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+4)(z^2-2z+2)}$$ and take the imaginary part of the resulting integral.

Comment: It's the standard problem which is easily solved using Jordan's lemma. Type it in wikipedia.

Comment: I first take the poles in the upper half plane, at $z = 2i , 1+i$.
I note that the integrand is equivalent to $\frac{1}{(z-2i)(z+2i)(z-i-1)(z-1=i)}\sin z$ 
I think here I compute the residues. I think the residue at $z=2i$ is $\frac{e^{-2}}{20}$. Not sure thereafter.

Comment: @luka5z You don't really need Jordan's lemma when the degree in the denominator is that large. (But of course, it doesn't hurt either.)

Comment: @user3677952 Did you read my first comment? You can't work with the integrand directly, since the integral along a large semi-circle doesn't tend to $0$

Comment: @mrf That's true. But on it's wikipedia page there is nice example how to solve such an integral (in this case op needs to take imaginary part afterwards)

Comment: My mistake, I should have noted that. I used $e^{iz}$ instead and took the imaginary part for the residue that I computed.

Comment: Once I have the residues, am I done?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the curve $C^r=C_1^r+C_2^r$ where $C_1^r$ is parameterized with $\sigma(t)=(t,0) , t\in[-r,r]$ and $C_2^r$ is parameterized with $\sigma(t)=re^{it}, t\in[0,\pi]$.

$f$ has $2$ poles into $C_r$ for $r$ sufficiently longer, by residues theorem $\int_{C_r} f dz$ is the sum of this residues. 
Now, if you prove that $\int_{C_2^r}f dz\to_r 0$, the problem is resolved making $r\to \infty$.

Comment: What $f$ are you considering here?

Comment: f is the function of the problem... f(z)=sinz/(z^2+4)(z^2-2z+2)

Comment: That won't work. (The integral of that $f$ along the semi-circle doesn't tend to $0$.)